# using cookies for single sign on with sso server

Tags: jsp, single-sign-on

Is it possible to implement Single Sign On using an Authentication Server(IDP) using cookies ?

Here is the scenario :

1. we have multiple web applications (esp's) .
2. Each esp may  request this idp to authenticate a user .
3. Now idp authenticates the user via any desired authentication protocol and stores a cookie in user's browser with time stamp maybe .
4. Now next time when another esp requests for user authentication , first of all idp checks if there exists a cookie in the browser , If it exists it authenticates user otherwise it again goes through the authentication process with the user .

Please guide me if i am on going right track .

Comment: If this is SAML IdP then the IdP should already detect that the user already has a session established. At least this is the case for OpenAM based SAML IdP.

Only if the SP requests to force authentication (using a specific parameter in the authentication request) the IdP prompts for authentication again.

Comment: Actually we want to implement some differrent authentication method . Can you please tell how can we configure idp to user our custom authentication method rather than user-password .

Comment: the SP can ask for a specific auth context 'class' in the authentication request ... on the IdP side this auth context 'class' can typically be mapped to authentication schemes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are suggesting is sometimes referred to as "Persistent Login Cookie authentication" or simply "Remember me authentication" and it's a standard practice. You can find a good article on how to implement such mechanism securely at http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Some frameworks like Spring Security have this concept implemented in their stack. You might also look into ready-made single sign-on frameworks like [Jasig CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) which tend to have these features available.

Comment: Hey thanx for answering sir . May  be i am a bit confused here . Why do we need to share cookies . We are making the request from same browser and only idp needs to check if cookie exists or not , as (each) ESP's are redirecting to IDP only whenever user requests to access the service . ESP's dont need to bother about cookie . Please   correct me where i am getting it wrong .

Comment: You are right, I misread your question and was proposing you a mechanism of communication between IDP and ESP... I'll update the answer soon.